# Solving second order ODE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I want to find the particular solution to
$$y''-2y'-y=\sin(3x)$$
by calculating $\Im(z)$ where 
$$z''-2z'-z=e^{3ix}$$
for $z(x)=e^{3ix}u(x)$ where $u(x)$ is some complex function. But with $z(x)=e^{3ix}u(x)$ we get:
$$z'(x) = e^{3ix}(u'(x)+3iu(x)) \\
z''(x) = e^{3ix}(u''(x)+6iu'(x)-9u(x))$$
And so
$$z''-2z-z=e^{3ix} \\
\Leftrightarrow
e^{3ix}(u''(x)+6iu'(x)-9u(x)) - 2e^{3ix} (u'(x)+3iu(x)) -e^{3ix}u(x)= e^{3ix} \\
\Leftrightarrow u''(x)+6iu'(x)-2u'(x)-10u(x)-6iu(x)=1$$
How can I solve this equation? Have I done something wrong?

Comment: Please check the first equation : may be, one of the $y$'s is $y'$.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong besides the typo Claude notes -- if you solve the equation for u, then you should have your solution.  The issue is that your assumption about the form of z(x) has not made your life easier.  It looks a little bit like doing a reduction of order, and a little bit like the method of undetermined coefficients, but it's not quite either.

Comment: A standard technique here is to use undetermined coefficients.  In this case, because $sin(3x)$ is not a solution of the complementary homogeneous equation $y'' - 2y - y = 0$, the appropriate form of guess is $A e^{3ix} + Be^{-3ix}$, for some complex constants $A$ and $B$.  Substitute this in as your guess for $z$ and you should be able to solve for $A$ and $B$.  (Alternatively, you may use variation of parameters)

Comment: Do you have any particular reason to do it that way ? If not, I think that you are making life more complex than required. By the way, the post has been edited but there is still the same problem. Cheers :-)

Comment: Do you know how to apply integral transform methods, such as Laplace or Fourier, to solve linear ODEs with constant coefficients?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I agree, it seems they tried to go that route when there is indeed a much simpler way to find a solution using method of undetermined coefficients.

Comment: @jm324354. May be there is a good reason but I cannot see which one could justify *complexity* (ahah !). Cheers

Comment: @jm324354
I know that I can solve it in other ways but I want to solve it this way.

Comment: Fix it also in the $z$'s

Comment: @Dr.MV No I don't.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying $z(x)=e^{3ix}u(x)$, try $z(x)=e^{3ix}U$, with a constant.

Then $z'(x)=3iz(x)$, $z''(x)=-9z(x)$ and $z''-2z-z=(-9+3i+1)z=\dfrac zU$, or 
$$z=\frac{e^{3ix}}{-8+3i}.$$

Answer (score 0):

I think what's happened here is that the solution to the homogeneous equation
$$ y''-2y'-y=0 $$
is of the form
$$ e^{-x}(Ae^{\sqrt{2}x}+Be^{-\sqrt{2}x}) $$
(the auxiliary equation is $k^2-2k-1=0$, with solutions $k=1 \pm \sqrt{2}$), so you substitution has not actually simplified things: this component of the equation is still going to have complex coefficients.

On the other hand, solving an inhomogeneous equation with a constant on the right is quite easy: it's just a constant scaled to agree with the coefficient of the constant term on the left.

Comment: You have typo's  in the equation and the auxiliary equation does not match.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Better?

Comment: @Chappers The auxiliary eq. is $r^2-2r-1=0$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Okay, I think that's done it.

Comment: @Chappers. Perfect, now !

Answer (score 0):

can i try to find a particular solution to $y''-2y' - y = \sin 3x$ in the form $$  y = a \cos 3x + b \sin 3x, y' = -3a\sin 3x + 3b \cos 3x, y''=-9a\cos 3x - 9b \sin 3x.$$  subbing all these in, we get $$-9a\cos 3x - 9b \sin 3x-2(-3a\sin 3x + 3b \cos 3x)-(a\cos 3x + b \sin 3x) = \sin 3x. $$ equating the coefficients we find 
$$-10a-6b=0, -10b+6a = 1 \to a = \frac 3{68}, b = - \frac 5{68}$$

so a particular solution is $$y = \frac 1{68}\left(3\cos 3x -5\sin 3x\right). $$

Answer (score 0):

As this differential equation is non-homogenous(because it has a forcing function sin(3x) on the R.H.S,the solution to this differential equation is the sum of the complimentary function(for the unforced system) and the particular integral.

write the given ODE in symbolic form. That gives

(D^2 + D + 1)=0 (For complimentary function)

the solution is D= -0.5 +- 0.866j

C.F= e^(0.5x){C1cos(0.866x)+C2 sin(0.866x)......(1)

Now for the particular integral.
the forcing function is sin(3x) which is of the form sin(ax) with a=3
Now P.I= sin(3x)/(D^2 + D + 1)
put D^2= -(a^2)=-9
then, P.I.= sin(3x)/(D-8)
Multiply and divide by D+8(conjugate)
then, P.I= sin(3x)(D+8)/((D^2-64))
again put D^2=-9

P.I= sin(3x)(D+8)/-73
now as D is d/dt
P.I.= - {(3cos(3x)+8sin(3x)}/73........(2)

the total solution is (1) + (2)